# If february is selected then it should show 29 days using JQuery Date Dropdown

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker, jquery-ui-droppable, datedropper

Here, I am using

> JQuery Date Dropdown

I am using **displayformat** is **'mdy'**. I want to show 29 days whenever feb is selected.

Comment: Do you mean on **every** February, not just leap years?

Comment: Yes @ÁlvaroGonzález and then automatically it will set the days to 28 if there is not a leap year. I specified the format 'mdy'

Comment: I see you edited the question to refer to a [different date picker](https://github.com/IckleChris/jquery-date-dropdowns) and then edited again to remove the link. You should make it really clear what library this is all about or otherwise the question is impossible to answer. Whatever, if the library provides hooks for callbacks you might be able to inject custom elements in the generated DOM but any kind of internal date calculation is likely to ignore it or even break entirely. Depending on your ultimate goal, you may get faster results writing custom code from scratch.

Comment: Apologies. firstly i wrote bootstrap datetimepicker but i was wrong. Now i just updated my question correctly. You can see the documentation online. I am unable to write custom function as this plugin is not giving me permission to override.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery datepicker

It will show Feb 29 on leap year automatically

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: This is not i asked.

Comment: then you should have posted your code. then only it will be easy to help